# OAuth2/REST : Protecting a project's API using another project's tokens

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I need your advice to find the best solution to my problem :

1. I have a PHP/Symfony API REST project ("PR1"), with an OAuth2 Server : This project's APIs are secured using OAuth2 tokens and work perfectly fine. This same project can generate OAuth2 tokens through its endpoints (/authorize & /token) and use them to access to the local API (/api/v1/users).
2. I have another PHP/Symfony API REST project ("PR2") : This project's APIs are "open" for access (not secured), but can communicate with PR1's API using an OAuth2 Client (back to back) : PR2 APIs can call protected PR1 APIs without problem as well using the client id/secret combo.

Now here is my issue : I would like to secure the open PR2 APIs (which are now not-secured) with OAuth2 tokens that can be generated from PR1.

I know I can set a new OAuth2 Server that can generate OAuth2 tokens, and replicate what I had done previously on PR1 in PR2 as well and it would work fine.
But I also want to keep a unique OAuth2 Server that manages OAuth2 tokens (checking and generating), which is PR1, for both PR1 and PR2 APIs.

Is there any easy way to make PR2's APIs secured with OAuth2 tokens, while the server is in another project (PR1) ?
Thanks in advance!

I used trikoder/oauth2-bundle (PHP League) as an OAuth2 server on PR1.
I can easily secure PR1 APIs using the security.yaml :

```
security:
 firewalls:
  api:
   pattern: ^/api(?!/doc)
   security: true
   stateless: true
   oauth2: true
```

I would like to do the same for PR2, but without installing another OAuth2 server and use the same one on PR1.

Here's how I see the process :

- The user can generate an OAuth2 token through a new endpoint on PR2 (/oauth/token) using PR1 (b2b calls) : I can already get the OAuth2 token from PR2 through PR1 without problems
- The user uses this OAuth2 token to access to PR2 Api : stuck here : I can't even "lock" the APIs on PR2 as I'm not sure what to put on the security.yaml, let alone use the OAuth2 token to unlock the access.

How would you make this process work ?

Comment: TLDR: rather configure the same token database

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I couldn't find a way to check the token from the PR1 as it wasn't possible (there's no OAuth2 server on it), but I was able to find a workaround : Make the OAuth2 Server (PR2) check the token if it's a valid one, using some listeners on the API project (PR1).
That way, when a user tries to access the PR1 using an OAuth2 token, I first check if the token is a valid before granting access.

Comment: I´m glad you solved it ! That was exactly what i mean